# batch insert in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I would like to batch insert to Postgresql on java.
I need statement with pattern: `insert into a(x,y) values (x1,y1),(x2,y2),...;` 
Am i right that using preparedStatement does not fit for it.
If i use:

```
            ps.setLong(1, id);
            ps.setInt(2, i);
            psRegion.addBatch();
```

in preparedStatement there is an array query with

```
insert into a(x,y) values (x1,y1);
insert into a(x,y) values (x2,y2);
...
```

Is there a programmatically solution besides use StringBuilder?

Comment: You can use `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` in the connection URL https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you require a single statement? Have you detected any performance issue using batch with the prepared statement?

Comment: one time i need it to detecte perfomance difference between 2 db

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can i get full string after adding all parameters?